# Updating loading bar from long task

Tags: ios, swift, loading

I'm trying to make a loading bar as I complete a long function can could take several seconds. However I'm not sure how I can figure out how far along in the functions execution I am and how to trigger the changes in the UI. Below is what I have which works ok, but I won't behave exactly as desired. Any suggestions?

```
func build(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Compiling Latest Clean Build", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: buildLbl.font])
    buildLbl.attributedText = myMutableString

    let greenStrip = UIView()
    greenStrip.backgroundColor = Colors().green
    greenStrip.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: buildStatus.frame.height - 2.5, width: 10, height: 2.5)
    buildStatus.addSubview(greenStrip)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
        // compile can take a while
        compile(structureContent: structuredContent)
        greenStrip.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.buildStatus.frame.height - 2.5, width: self.buildStatus.frame.width, height: 2.5)

    }, completion: {
        (value: Bool) in

        greenStrip.removeFromSuperview()
        let dvc : PreviewViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PreviewViewController") as! PreviewViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(dvc, animated: false)

    })

}
```

Comment: I can help you if I know about your long function. Can you briefly tell us what your long function is doing and how are you implementing it?

Comment: The `compile()` function is mostly writing to files. It is also saving images and sounds. It iterates through a data structure and writes to files or saves things basically.

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep track of progress made from your `compile()` function that is looping through a data structure and do stuff. First, you need a delegate function from your `compile()` function that reports the progress as percentage so that you can later display that on UI. You can find a complete tutorial about delegate [here](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/) and your protocol will look something like

```
protocol ProgressDelegate: class {
    func didFinishTask(progress: Double)
}
```

Now here is a sample way of reporting progress. At the beginning of your `compile()` function, you want to get a count  from your data structure as total jobs. Then in each round of your for loop, you divide the current loop count by total count and then report this progress by the delegate. So your code will look something like

```
func compile(){
    ...
    let totalJobs = jobs.count
    let counter = 0.0
    for eachJob in jobs {
        counter += 1.0
        ...
        didFinishTask(progress: counter/totalJobs)
    }
}
```

Finally, in your UI view controller that receives this delegate. Update UI base one the percentage finished of your task.

```
func didFinishTask(progress: Double){
    // set up status bar here
}
```